# Exercise reccomendation for 11 year old kid

Tags: exercise, bodyweight-exercises

What fitness exercise, gym exercise, or Crossfit exercises are recommended for an 11-year-old guy?

Comment: Are you the 11 year old kid?

Comment: What's the objective? General fitness, some other specific goal? Maybe [edit] the question to add more details.

Answer (score -1):

As someone who has trained for sport for 10+ years, but is without any sort of training certification, I would recommend starting with some of the following bodyweight movements:

For Lower Body:

- squats
- nordic hamstring curls (have a partner hold ankles down)
- hamstring curl on a stability/yoga ball
- calf raises
- glute bridges (single or both legs)
- lunges

For upper body, at a young age, I find the risk-reward ratio of doing exercises with improper form to be pretty undesirable, so these are some where even poor form shouldn't present serious concern for joint/back health.

- pull/chin ups
- wall (incline) pushups
- static planks
- dead bugs
- quadruped arm-leg raise
- upright rows*
- shrugs

*if you can find a bar or something else to grab thats about chest-high, place your feet under, lean back (keep core tight), and pull your chest to the bar

Simply running/biking/swimming/hiking is a good workout for young kids too. If you can find a hill near you, you can get creative with efficient workouts that work most of your body.

Try this one out: Sprint 10-20 meters up a hill, walk down to bottom. For a total of 15 sprints.

Comment: Would be interesting to know why my answer is being down-voted here... I don't think any of these are radical suggestions

Comment: can't imagine why it was downvoted. like in the meme where one from a group of people shows thumb down never mind what was said. upvoted the answer, btw.